# iframe closes when trying to change its src value

Tags: iframe, uri, src

I am at an absolute loss in this situation.  I've tried changing the src value of an iframe with pure JS and jQuery, but both attempts just close the iframe object!

I have an iframe in the HTML as defined:

```
<body>
<div id="divBody">
   <img src="images/test.gif" onClick="...see_below..." />
   <iframe name="ifTarget" id="ifTarget" src="http://www.yahoo.com" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

I also have an img on the page that, when clicked, should change the src of that iframe as defined:

```
document.getElementById('ifTarget').setAttribute('src', 'http://www.google.com');
```

and alternatively via jQuery:

```
$('#ifTarget').attr('src','http://www.google.com');
```

In both cases, the iframe just closes down an I'm left with the following error via FF Error Console:

```
Security Error: Content at https://www.google.com/ may not load data from http://127.0.0.1/.
```

I am running this from the local computer, but I get this same message if run from a hosting company (with the trialing URI adjusted accordingly).  Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Some websites won't allow themselves to be put in any kind of frame.